# show all controls(volume,progressbar,done..)in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to show all the controls in mpmovieplayercontroller.By default it shows all controls like..(volume,progressbar,done..).At some point i remove all the controls from movieplayer using this line of code:`moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;`
Then i want to show all the controls again .for that,this code not supporting `appDelegate.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;`.

Any one please help me how can i show all the controls in movieplayer.

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

I think

`appDelegate.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;`

should be

`appDelegate.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;`